# getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri) create blank image on Android 11/API 30

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am working on app which needs to download images/videos from server and save it to mediastore and at the local app database with it's URI like `content://media/external/images/media/10052` which loads after download on app from URI.

When app receive an image from server it first download with the help of this method on Android 11/API 30.

```
private Uri mediaStoreInsert(String fileName, String mimeType, String directoryPath){
        Log.d(TAG, "mediaStoreInsert: Values = "+fileName+" "+directoryPath+" "+mimeType);
        ContentResolver resolver = MyApplication.getmContext().getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/"+directoryPath);
        Uri mediaStore;
        if (mimeType.equals(imageType)){
           mediaStore = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        }else {
           mediaStore = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        }
        Uri uri = resolver.insert(mediaStore, contentValues);
        Log.d(TAG, "mediaStoreInssert: URI Check = "+uri);
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = MyApplication.getmContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return uri;
    }
```

This method returns `URI` of image but when i check image in gallery it shows blank image with 0 bytes. Can you please help me why this method not creating image successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing anything.

```java
            outputStream = MyApplication.getmContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
```

Here you open the `OutputStream`, then close it. You do not write anything to that stream.

Comment: should i write file first then run this code ` resolver.insert(mediaStore, contentValues);` or code is perfect i just need to write to stream. Can you please show me how to write an image with same content uri

Comment: @Ritu: "Perfect" is a very high bar.  But between the `openInputStream()` call and the call to `flush()` on that stream, you need to write your content to the stream. This is not tied to Android -- Java I/O has been around for 20+ years.

Comment: You are right. Perfect is high bar but for me first it should work as i need it to work. `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);` this is the way i get to know for writing stram. but i don't need any bitmap to create or compress (taking extra resources). Is there any better way to do it so i can return uri

Comment: @Ritu: Your data has to come from somewhere. I do not know where you plan to get your data from, and so I cannot tell you how to write that data to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: the data coming from internet. it can be random URL, `https://previews.123rf.com/images/haywiremedia/haywiremedia1001/haywiremedia100100006/6159925-a-closeup-of-a-technology-internet-url-address-being-typed-out-on-a-computer-screen-a-mouse-is-on-th.jpg`

Comment: @Ritu: Then you should focus on how you are going to download those bytes, with an eye towards writing those bytes to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237338/discussion-between-ritu-and-commonsware).